Opensips get current value of Header
I'm new to opensips,
I have sip Flow like this:

A send Invite to Opensips Server X
X send Invite to devices IpPhone connect to extension 102
Devices Iphone still not pickup call yet, it transfer to another extension, this case will send to X an 302 Message like picture bellow to refer call co extension 100
Opensips at X receive Message like bellow with contact field is 100@domain
The Problem is i can get this field by this code: $hdr(Contact) , or $ct
its always return value of first Contact value at step 1 ( A send to X)

How can i get new Contact field from header to override to Message.
Please help me solve this.


During reply processing in your opensips.cfg file, in order to get the value of the Contact header of the SIP reply and not the request, use the $(<reply>ct) pseudo-variable instead of simply $ct.
If there are multiple Contact header fields in the reply, they can be indexed as: $(<reply>ct[0]), $(<reply>ct[1])... .  Full docs here.
